# Laravel 5.1 flash message handling

Tags: php, session, laravel, laravel-5.1, flash-message

In Laravel 5.0 and 4.* there was this option to check if the Session had flash_messages:

Controller:

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    Session::flash('flash_message', 'Success');
    return redirect('somepage');
}
```

And then you could call this in your layout:

```
@if (Session::has('flash_message'))
    <p>{{ Session::get('flash_message') }}</p>
@endif
```

This worked perfectly fine, however in Laravel 5.1 it changed. Now it's stored in the request variable. So, I changed it in the controller to:

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    $request->session()->flash('flash_message', 'Success');
    return redirect('somepage');
}
```

And I call this in the layout:

```
@if($request->session()->has('flash_message'))
    <p>{{ $request->session()->get('flash_message') }}</p>
@endif
```

I'm doing exactly what is stated in the Laravel 5.1 docs:

> **Determining If An Item Exists In The Session**
>
> The has method may be used to check if an item exists in the session.
>   This method will return true if the item exists:
>
> `if ($request->session()->has('users')) { // }`

Now this works perfectly fine for store method now, because I only added a flash_message there, but if I want to access another method like index, create, edit, etc. it shows this error:

> ErrorException
>
> Undefined variable: request

I understand that the request variable is not declared in the other methods and I can workaround this if-statement using `isset($request)`.

Is there a better solution to check if my flash_message is set in the `$request` variable like in the earlier versions of Laravel?

Comment: You can still use the `Session` facade in your Blade view just like in Laravel 4. The example used in the documentation is using `Request` to show method parameter injection.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're using controllers generated by Laravel.

If you look at the method definitions for `store` and `update` you'll find the parameter `Request $request`. By including this Laravel automatically creates a `Request` instance for you.

In order to access this in other methods you have three options:

Add the same parameter to any of the other method definitions and Laravel will generate it for you in the same way.

Create a constructor function and have it assign a `Request` instance to an attribute.

```
public function __construct(Request $request)
{
     $this->request = $request;
}
```

Declare `use Session;` before the class definition to make the `Session` class accessible in your namespace.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use the old method :) . latest laravel just added new ways to achieve that goal.here goes the sample code to display error messages which are passed as flash message into a view page  .

### Sample code

```
@if ($message = Session::get('success'))
 <div class="alert alert-success alert-block">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
  <h4>Success</h4>
  @if(is_array($message))
   @foreach ($message as $m)
    {{ $m }}
   @endforeach
  @else
   {{ $message }}
  @endif
 </div>
@endif
```